# Validating input read from a file in Java

Tags: java, validation

I'm working on an assignment that is broken down into different methods and I'm currently stuck on one of them.

I'm supposed to be reading in data from a file who's format looks like this:

```
46813 5 100.00
```

The first number is an integer between 0 and 99999, the second is an integer between 0 and 5, and the last number is a double between 0.00 and 100.00.

Here's my code for the method which is supposed to read input and save any errors in the data. For example, the number 6 if it appeared in the second column and so on and so forth. Right now I'm using `println` to see if my data is being captured correctly before I attempt saving any values, but I'm pretty much clueless.

I've been on stuck on this for hours doing several different things but I can never get close. If there's an easier method to doing all of this please, let me know. I'm willing to learn.

The file I'm reading from:

```
46813  5  100.00
80795  4  86.52
34961  3  77.52
40059  2  85.61
80463  1  70.16
64088  0  80.52
65400  6  90.23
80775  2  70.16
573S1  3  83.03
21076  4  54.47
32911  5  -10.90
```

The code:

```
public static void validateData() throws IOException {
    File myfile = new File("gradeInput.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myfile);
    int b = 0;
    double f = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        int a = inputFile.nextInt();
        if (a < 0 || a > 99999) {
            b = a;
            System.out.println(b);
        }
        int c = inputFile.nextInt();
        if (c < 0 || c > 5) {
            b = c;
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        double d = inputFile.nextDouble();
        if (d < 0 || d > 100.00) {
            f = d;
            System.out.println(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide 3 or 4 example lines for "gradeInput.txt"?

Comment: 46813  5  100.00
80795  4  86.52
34961  3  77.52
40059  2  85.61
80463  1  70.16
64088  0  80.52
65400  6  90.23
80775  2  70.16
573S1  3  83.03
21076  4  54.47
32911  5  -10.90 I'll try and add this in to the post.

Comment: This one contains a letter - 573S1, what is it? Also you have negatives. This doesn't quite match your textual description of the format.

Comment: @peter.petrov those would count as errors that I would need to save. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough before.

Comment: Right, I got it. See below how you can check for such validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read them as strings, validate them e.g. by trying to parse them to
integers, longs, floats, doubles, and whatever they are supposed to be.
Currently you don't validate anything, you just read them assuming that
they are valid. Here is a simple method to test if a string is a valid
integer.

```
    private static boolean isValidInteger(String num){
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(num);
            return true;
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You should do the same for long, float, double, and whatever types you need.

[Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

[Long.parseLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29)

[Float.parseFloat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29)

[Double.parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used this input file:

```
46813 5 100.00
80795 4 86.52
34961 3 77.52
```

And this java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class FileParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        validateData();
    }

    public static void validateData() throws IOException {

        // open file
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "/.../gradeInput.txt"));

        // define variable for line of file
        String line;

        // read file line by line, until there are no more lines
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Next line:");

            String[] lineContents = line.split(" ");

            int firstContent = Integer.parseInt(lineContents[0]);
            System.out.println(firstContent);

            int secondContent = Integer.parseInt(lineContents[1]);
            System.out.println(secondContent);

            Number thirdContent = new BigDecimal(lineContents[2]);
            System.out.println(thirdContent);

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

to get this output:

```
Next line:
46813
5
100.00

Next line:
80795
4
86.52

Next line:
34961
3
77.52
```

I'm not 100% sure, whether your input file contains line breaks and/or commas. You might have to change the code a bit to fit your requirements.